# RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 16 => What is form data precisely?

Tags: windows

Hail all:

Though I am 52, and active with computers since 1986 (those were more oversized calculators, to be correct), i have no idea what is meant with Form Data.

I know, I know, this is insane, but i just never came across this before.
Might be, I DO know it, but by a different name, maybe Dutch.
Still I am quite stuck, to be quite honest.

Tried to google it, got heaps on information as to how to clear it, restore it, save it, unsave it, ... , but nowhere an in-depth explanation of what is meant with form Data.

Now, I am building a Batch File, for speed-cleaning of certain data, when my Firefox starts to get slow ... .
Came across the "erase Form Data" command, but nae clue as to what Form Data is.

Thank you.
Ben

Answer (score 1):

That rundll32 command only applies to Internet Explorer and will not touch Firefox.

Anyway, form data is data entered into [html forms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) like your name, address and telephone etc. These form fields are edit boxes, check/radio buttons and drop-down selectors.

Firefox has its own setting to clear form data when you close the browser. Form data is very low on the list of what slows down your browser...

Comment: My excuses, 'tis very hectic here.

'tIs not the PC that slows down, but my browser.
Naturally, that is hooked on my PC so, yeah, one could say the PC is slowing.

Where did you get that it is the PC slowing, sir?
I never said that?

Comment: My excuses, 'tis very hectic here, hence the late reply.
'tIs not the PC that slows down, but my browser.

So this ode is useless to me, correct?